# Prevent sort by name from sorting descending order in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, sorting

It seems in Windows 7 (and most likely Vista as well) when you right click on the desktop, it'll sort by name in ascending order.  If you right click and sort again, it will sort in descending order.  And it will flip-flop that way ad nauseum.  How do I prevent that behaviour, as I want it to ALWAYS sort ascending order.  is there a group policy or registry hack I can apply to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no registry setting or group policy for this. The entries are hardcoded into the Shell. The "easiest" solution I can think of is writing a Shell extension that changes the Sorting context menu.  Unfortunately, this "easy solution" **also turns off this option for all folders**.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback even if it means it cannot be done easily.  Oh well.  I hope Windows 8 removes this feature or at least has the ability of disabling it from a control panel or a registry tweak.